# select_tag triggers another action in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A form can be submitted by pressing the `Submit` button or select an item in the `select_tag`:

```
<% form_tag url_for(:action => 'create') do %>

  <%= select_tag :names, options_from_collection_for_select(@name_list, :id, :name, @name), 
     { :onchange => "this.form.submit();" } %> 

  <%= submit_tag 'Submit' %>

<% end %>
```

Is it possible to invoke another controller action (other than `create`) in `this.form.submit();`?

I'd like to handle the different submissions in different actions, instead of:

```
if params[:commit] == 'Submit'
  # from submit
else
  # from select_tag
end
```

in the same controller action.

Answer (score 1):

in jQuery you could try something like:

```
:onchange => "$.post(<alternative_url>, $(this).form.serialize()); return false;"
```

[MY EARLIER RESPONSE (not answering the question)] 
how about using js for setting commit input value before submit?

jQuery:

```
:onchange => "$(this).form.find('input[name="commit"]').val('select'); $(this).form.submit();"
```

plain JS:

```
:onchange => "document.getElementById(<SubmitButtonId>).value = 'select'; this.form.submit;"
```

Comment: This still goes to the same action in controller, doesn't it?

Comment: yes yes, this just sets the commit param you can fork on in the controller. hopefully :)

Comment: ooops my bad, this is exactly NOT what you want. mmm.

Comment: I edited my response, is it working or you do not use jQuery?